# Why does foldr invert foldl's parameters?

Tags: haskell, fold

This is a very, very simple foldl function: it takes a list, and returns the same list:

```
identityL :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
identityL xs = foldl (\ acc x -> acc ++ [x]) [] xs
```

I tried to do the same thing with foldr, thinking that all I had to do was change foldl to foldr and flip "acc" and "[x]" around the "++".  But apparently, you need to flip the parameters as well:

```
identityR :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
identityR xs = foldr (\ x acc -> [x] ++ acc) [] xs
```

This seems very counter-intuitive, for a function that seems to serve the purpose of linearly processing a list against an accumulator.  I am probably approaching the concept incorrectly; is there a simple model of the fold that justifies the weirdness of flipping the parameters?

EDIT: This was silly; as pointed out, the parameter orderings offset each other. The following code works:

```
identityR :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a]
identityR xs = foldr (\ acc x -> [acc] ++ x) [] xs
```

I saw this before, but it bothers me because the `acc` should be a list and not need list encapsulation, whereas the `x` should.

However, when you look at what the folds are really doing, it makes perfect sense to invert the `x` and `acc` variables.

Given the list [1,2,3], identityL is successively ++'ing an `[x]` to the existing `acc`:

```
((([] ++ [1]) ++ [2]) ++ [3])
```

whereas identityR is successively ++'ing an `acc` to the starting `[x]`:

```
([1] ++ ([2] ++ ([3] ++ [])))
```

Comment: It's counter-intuitive to what a lot of programmers are used to in terms of API, but it is intuitive and fitting in terms of the actual fold operation. The order you are given is inverted because the operation is inverted, so to speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `foldr` and `foldl` pass the list to the function with the arguments in the same order.

```
foldr (+) 0 [1, 2, 3] = 1 + (2 + (3 + 0))
foldl (+) 0 [1, 2, 3] = ((0 + 1) + 2) + 3
```

That's all there is to it.

```
> foldr (\x y -> "(" ++ show x ++ " + " ++ y ++ ")") "0" [1, 2, 3]
"(1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))"
> foldl (\x y -> "(" ++ x ++ " + " ++ show y ++ ")") "0" [1, 2, 3]
"(((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)"
```

### Math

Suppose you have a monoid, M:

```
identity :: M
op :: M -> M -> M

-- Monoid laws:
-- x `op` (y `op` z) = (x `op` y) `op` z
-- x `op` identity = x
-- identity `op` x = x
```

The way `foldr` and `foldl` are defined, `foldr` and `foldl` always give the same result, assuming `op` is total.  They're just different ways of parenthesizing the same expression.

```
foldr op identity == foldl op identity
```

For example,

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
-- both definitions give same result
concat = foldr (++) []
concat = foldl (++) []

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
-- both definitions give same result
sum = foldr (+) 0
sum = foldl (+) 0

product :: Num a => [a] -> a
-- both definitions give same result
product = foldr (*) 1
product = foldl (*) 1
```

For non-associative operations, this is irrelevant because `foldr` and `foldl` won't generally give the same result.  For commutative operations, this is irrelevant because `foldr` and `foldl` will give the same result no matter what order the arguments go in.  This is only helpful for monoids in general.

Or, put another way, you can think of `foldr` and `foldl` as tools for transforming the free monoid (a.k.a the list) into another monoid of your choosing.

Comment: It's not afaik; in your example the order is just irrelevant.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by "it's not afaik".  The example illustrates evaluation order with parentheses, it is irrelevant that the order is irrelevant.

Comment: @MasterMastic: It's not relevant that the result would be different.  I'm just illustrating the structure of how the function is evaluated.

Comment: True, I had just removed that comment. The following is what I meant to illustrate through it before noticing I'm not :P
`foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b` while `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`.
`foldl` takes the accumulator first and argument second, while `foldr` takes the argument first and accumulator second.

Comment: What I had meant to write in the commented I removed was: `foldl (-) 0 [1..10] == foldr (flip (-)) 0 [1..10]` which is -55.

Comment: @DietrichEpp So the reason the parameters are inverted is to guarantee that for non-commutative monoids `foldr` and `foldl` give the same result?

Comment: @Beks_Omega: It's certainly a nice property that for all monoids, `foldr` and `foldl` give the same result. I think the real reason here is just that it makes intuitive sense to have the accumulated value on the right for `foldr` and on the left for `foldl`.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of `foldr` as replacing `(:)` and `[]` in the list, then the order of arguments passed to the function makes perfect sense:

```
xs =           x1  :  x2  :  x3  :  ...  :  []
foldr f a xs = x1 `f` x2 `f` x3 `f` ... `f` a
```